# Using aliases with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I tried using alias using `select` with `eloquent`, it has given me weird results

my code:

```
$caseStudy = CaseStudy::find($id)->select('title_case as title','description_case as description')->get();
```

It returned collection. My question is to find model and change the column names. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find function can take an array as a second parameter.
In this array you can list the fields you need.

```
$caseStudy = CaseStudy::find($id, ['title_case as title','description_case as description']);
```

This way you should be able to access your aliases:

```
$caseStudy->title
```

Instead of:

```
$caseStudy->title_case
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
$caseStudy = CaseStudy::select(DB::raw('title_case as title','description_case as description'))->find($id)->get();
```